# Am I missing potential problems with custom page caching in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I use rails to present automated hardware testing results; our tests are run mainly via TCL. Recently, we have implemented a "log4TCL" which is basically a translated version of log4J. The log files have upwards of 40000 lines, each of which is written to the database as a logline record, and load time for the view is too long to be considered usable. I have tried to use ajax requests to speed things up, but the initial query/page load accounts for ~75% of the full page load.

My solution is page caching. I cannot use the rails included page caching because each log report is a different instance of "log_viewer". The report is generated using a test_run_id parameter. Rails-included page caching only caches one instance of "log_viewer.html". What I need is "log_viewer_#{test_run_id}.html". I have implemented a way of doing this. The reports age out after one week and are purged from the test_runs/log_viewer_cache directory to save disk space. If an older report is needed, loading the page re-generates the report with a fresh age-out timer.

I have come to the conclusion that this is the way to go. My concern is that I have not found any other implementations such as this anywhere which leads me to believe that I have missed an inherent flaw in my design.  Any input would be much appreciated.

EDIT: For clarification, the "Dynamic" content of this report is what takes too long to load. I need to cache multiple instances of what action/fragment caching is not concerned with.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have implemented a way of doing this"? There's built-in fragment and action caching which is specifically designed to achieve what you need.

Comment: It is the action that takes so long to complete. The page layout is trivial in its load time. I have rendered the report as a partial using render_to_string and then written it to a file. The main issue here is, rather than having one log_viewer to cache, I have > 600 different reports, each of which need to load around 40000 records,  that are all derived from the log_viewer controller/view.  EDIT: Make comment more concise.

Comment: For clarification, the "Dynamic" content of this report is what takes too long to load. I need to cache multiple instances of what action/fragment caching is not concerned with.

Comment: I think you didn't really check what action caching is and what are possibilities with it. Plus - file store is super slow unless you have optimized system with ramdisk or ssd storage.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks for your help. I'll take some more time to understand action caching a little better.